# phpMyAdmin no funciona en Docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker

Estoy intentando hacer un LAMP con Docker compose de la cula muchas cosas me han funcionado pero lo que siempre me sucede es que no puedo acceder a la BD desde phpMyAdmin ya que siempre me dice que "El servidor MySQL no autorizo su acceso" y de paso me dice **MySQL exited with code 1.**
Espero me puedan orientar en donde esta mi error.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  www:
    build: .
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - lamp-docker

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: MySQL
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - lamp-docker

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: PHPmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - lamp-docker

networks:
  lamp-docker:
    driver: bridge
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Las variables de entorno del docker de BBDD no son correctas:

```
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
  MYSQL_USER: root                  <--- valor root no válido en esta variable
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
```

Estas indicando la variable MYSQL_USER con el usuario root. Esto es erroneo (en el log del docker de mysql te lo dice):

```
2024-01-23 23:27:39+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
    Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
```

Lo puedes solucionar quitando la variable MYSQL_USER y MYSQL_PASSWORD del entorno, O cambiando el valor de MYSQL_USER a un usuario distinto a ROOT.